# Calculate Kappa statistic in R

Tags: r, random-forest, cohens-kappa

Currently I am trying to calculate Kappa for a confusion matrix. Unfortunately, I never used Kappa in R before. I found this description how to use it:

class1
A vector describing a classification of experimental units.
reference
A vector describing the "correct" classification of the experimental units in class1

```
reference<-c("hi","low","low","hi","low","med","med")
class1<-c("hi","hi","low","hi","med","med","med")
Kappa(class1,reference)
```

Nevertheless, I could not run this code with my data, as I cannot figure out what I have to put into my reference and my class1.

Comment: One version is in the pavckage `irr` on CRAN

Answer (score 7):

Your `reference` and `class1` are correctly defined, but using a wrong function.

The function `kappa` in `R` base is not calculating Cohen's Kappa but "Compute or Estimate the Condition Number of a Matrix". See `?kappa`.

In stead you can try

```
caret::confusionMatrix(reference,class1)

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

Reference
Prediction hi low med
hi   2   0   0
low  1   1   1
med  0   0   2

Overall Statistics

Accuracy : 0.7143          
95% CI : (0.2904, 0.9633)
No Information Rate : 0.4286          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.1266          

Kappa : 0.5882
```